# Table Structure for versioning data

Tags: database, data-structures, versioning

I have a table to store data for the phones and it has about 50 columns .......... should be inserted on average 30 million phones in one year ........ however, it is necessary to store a history of these phones, for example, if I want to change a field in a phone at a given date, latter I need to know at any given time, the values that had this phone.
It occurred to me to have a historical and a main table, where in the main, I have the latest values of the cell, and in the historical all the changes that were made. Now this is a duplication of data, because if you change only one field, I insert into the historical table all the values, even those not changed, and in the main,this last record, so the historical table will grow enormously.
How could I manage to not store too much information that may not be changed and retrieve data from a phone at any given time?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the ability to query historical data easily then I would duplicate. Either copy via a trigger to a historical table or if the system has downtime create a table with an ID and timestamped unique constraint and during that down time using a scheduled batch process to move old data out. This older data would live elsewhere, could be compressed, and/or moved off the main disk to tape backup for instance.

On the other hand, as you suggest in your question, you could go down the road of individually versioning each field - and only those that changed - which would require less storage, but reconstructing the data at a given point then in time is more involved to the point I would probably would not use SQL, but instead rely in a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it looks like you need to query historical data before every update/insert to check if the phone details were used previously. In such scenario you can't just move historical data elsewhere, as was sugestested previously, you need to keep them alive forever. 
The one possible way to get somewhat reasonable performance for queries hitting the history table would be just to throw more hardware at the problem - partition the data in archive table across as many physical drives as you can afford.

Comment: No, the question never states every change requires querying historical data, but rather the ability to know the state at any given point in the past. So yes, historical data can moved elsewhere so long as it can be used later to recover old state.

Comment: Ok, maybe I misunderstood this part : "if I want to change a field in a phone at a given date, latter I need to know at any given time, the values that had this phone."